# Iterate all cells in s UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I want to iterate all uitablewview cells and display the text of a uitextview contained in each cell. 
My table can have many rows and to reach all you must scroll. I made an implementation, but it displays the text only for current visible cells in scroll, for the others gives me null.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [propertiesTableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++) {
    UITableViewCell* cell = [propertiesTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    UITextView* tx = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    NSString* temp = tx.text;
    NSLog(@"%@", temp);
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: i think this is not possible as the cell for the visible rows are created at pressent so other gives null

Comment: does your table get data from some sort of array or data source ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because only the visible cells are instantiated (remember the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` function?). You should extract the needed information from the table data source.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this behavior is expected, because of performance considerations the table view does not holds all cells initialized all the time. Your solution is just to update your data source - if it's an array for example, iterate though it and change the values accordingly - this is the power of MVC (fast UI, separate model)